# AttributeError: module Django.contrib.auth.views has no attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, attributeerror

In my Django app useraccounts, I created a Sign-Up form and a model for my Sign-up. However, when I went to run python manage.py makemigrations, I encounter the error: AttributeError: module Django.contrib.auth.views has no attribute 'registration'. Secondly, am I coding the SignUpForm in forms.py correctly? I did not want to use the User model in models because it would request username and I didn't want my website to ask for a username.

Here is my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name =  models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=150)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from useraccounts.models import UserProfile

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = ('first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'email',
                  'password1',
                  'password2', )
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from useraccounts.forms import SignUpForm

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'useraccounts/home.html')

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'useraccounts/login.html')

def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()
            user.profile.birth_date = form.cleaned_data.get('birth_date')
            user.save()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            form = SignUpForm()
        return render(request, 'registration.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.home),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'useraccounts/login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'template_name': 'useraccounts/logout.html'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^registration/$', auth_views.registration, {'template_name': 'useraccounts/registration.html'}, name='registration'),

]
```

Comment: Please post your full error traceback

Comment: Turns out that I messed up the url.py part for registration. Thanks for answering though!

Comment: Always write the Django Version as there is a lot of development going on in the versions.

Answer (score 67):

Open `urls.py` and replace:

`django.contrib.auth.views.login` with `django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView`

`django.contrib.auth.views.logout` with `django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView`

Answer (score 28):

Your **urlpatterns** should be:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
   url( r'^login/$',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="useraccounts/login.html"), name="login"),
]
```

Answer (score 19):

In django version 2.1  in custom urls patterns from auth app i use

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf import settings
from .views import register_view, activate


urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    re_path(r'^register/$', register_view, name='signup'),
    re_path(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
            activate, name='users_activate'),
    re_path('login/', auth_views.LoginView, {
        'template_name': "users/registration/login.html"},
        name='login'),
    re_path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView,
        {'next_page': settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL}, name='logout'),

    re_path(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView,
        {'template_name': "users/registration/password_reset_form.html"},
        name='password_reset'),
    re_path(r'^password_reset/done/$', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView,
        {'template_name': "users/registration/password_reset_done.html"},
        name='password_reset_done'),
    re_path(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView,
        {'template_name': "users/registration/password_reset_confirm.html"},
        name='password_reset_confirm'),
    re_path(r'^reset/done/$', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView,
        {'template_name': "users/registration/password_reset_complete.html"},
        name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

Answer (score 8):

Django 2.1 contrib views change from function view to class view and name also change so in forgot process you need to give other view name

### urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), {'template_name':'registration/Reset_email.html'}, name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), {'template_name':'registration/Reset_Email_Sent.html'}, name='password_reset_done'),
    re_path('reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), {'template_name' : 'registration/Forgot_password.html'}, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), {'template_name' : 'registration/Signin.html'}, name='password_reset_complete'),
```

Django you can customize user model and you can remove username and use email address

### models.py

user model you can write customize column you can add and you can delete

user manage also you can customize comond like super user if yo
u need to give any default value

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser,BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField( _('first name'), max_length=250)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=250)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name',]

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" %(self.email)
```

### settings.py

settings you need to give your custom user model

```
# AUTH USER MODEL
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "Accounts.User" 

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
#LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  = 'login_success'

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/login/'
```

### admin.py

admin you need to register user model

```
## user model view
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as DjangoUserAdmin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(DjangoUserAdmin):
    """Define admin model for custom User model with no email field."""

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email_confirmed')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                       'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name'),
        }),
    )
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name',)
    search_fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    ordering = ('-id',)
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to import the LoginView in your urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
```

and change

```
auth_view.login
```

to

```
LoginView.as_view()
```

Answer (score 5):

You need `LoginView`, etc. as a class and not a function as seen [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views) (new in Django 1.11 as `Should` and a Must from Version 2.1 on)

Answer (score 5):

Very Simple Steps:

Goto the Projects `urls.py`
change `views.login` to  `views.LoginView.as_view()`

if you are using Logout attribute then do the same with that

Answer (score 3):

it should be:

```
url(r'^registration/$', views.registration, {'template_name': 'useraccounts/registration.html'}, name='registration'),
```

auth_views does not have registration, your views does

Comment: Thanks. But now when I open useraccounts/registration.html, I get the error: "The view useraccounts.views.registration didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead." Also, did I do my forms and views correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Open `url.py` file and replace

`views.login` with `views.LoginView`

Comment: Could you add some more context to make your answer more appropriate?  e.g. what would the code be?  you are replacing a function with a class, so the syntax may not be the same.  You may also want to mention that this is only applicable to Django>=1.11

Comment: I got this error in django 2 when upgrading to 2.2.3 from 2 something.  I fixed my urls like...
  url(r'^accounts/login/$', django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView,name="login"),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView,{'next_page': '/'},name="logout"),

Answer (score 2):

I can't leave comments so I decided to leave an answer.
You have extra indent near else block. Your registration func should look like:

```
def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()
            user.profile.birth_date = form.cleaned_data.get('birth_date')
            user.save()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'registration.html', {'form': form})
```

This is why you get this error

> The view useraccounts.views.registration didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Answer (score 1):

Open urls.py and replace:

change `views.login` => `views.LoginView.as_view()`