# NameError: name 'LoginView' is not defined

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, openstack-horizon

I'm installing the Openstack Stein Horizon service (dashboard) following the tutorial on the site.
I encounter an error due to the Django version and fix it using this explanation [Switch from django string_concat to format_lazy](https://opendev.org/openstack/horizon/commit/6f4742457fae755e465315f17f39c3977c833d0e?style=unified).

The next issue that appears was **AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'login'**, which I googled and came again as a Django version incompatibility.
I followed this explanation here: [AttributeError: module Django.contrib.auth.views has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47065438/attributeerror-module-django-contrib-auth-views-has-no-attribute)

***openstack_auth/urls.py***

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views import generic

from openstack_auth import utils
from openstack_auth import views
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^login/$", LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    url(r"^logout/$", LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    url(r'^switch/(?P<tenant_id>[^/]+)/$', views.switch,
        name='switch_tenants'),
    url(r'^switch_services_region/(?P<region_name>[^/]+)/$',
        views.switch_region,
        name='switch_services_region'),
    url(r'^switch_keystone_provider/(?P<keystone_provider>[^/]+)/$',
        views.switch_keystone_provider,
        name='switch_keystone_provider')
]

if utils.is_websso_enabled():
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r"^websso/$", views.websso, name='websso'),
        url(r"^error/$",
            generic.TemplateView.as_view(template_name="403.html"))
    ]
```

***apache2/error.log***

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 141, in __call__
     response = self.get_response(request)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 75, in get_response
     response = self._middleware_chain(request)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
     response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
     response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 128, in handle_uncaught_exception
     callback, param_dict = resolver.resolve_error_handler(500)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 584, in resolve_error_handler
     callback = getattr(self.urlconf_module, 'handler%s' % view_type, None)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 564, in urlconf_module
     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openstack_dashboard/urls.py", line 53, in <module>
     urlpatterns.append(url(r'^auth/', include(u)))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openstack_auth/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
     url(r"^login/$", LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
   NameError: name 'LoginView' is not defined
```

**Django version: 2.2**

Thks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did import the `django.contrib.auth.views` module as `auth_views`, not the `LoginView`, `LogoutView`, etc. from that module. You can thus for example use `auth_views.LoginView`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^login/$", auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    url(r"^logout/$", auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    url(r'^switch/(?P<tenant_id>[^/]+)/$', views.switch,
        name='switch_tenants'),
    url(r'^switch_services_region/(?P<region_name>[^/]+)/$',
        views.switch_region,
        name='switch_services_region'),
    url(r'^switch_keystone_provider/(?P<keystone_provider>[^/]+)/$',
        views.switch_keystone_provider,
        name='switch_keystone_provider')
]
```

or you can import the `LoginView` and `LogoutView` from that module:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^login/$", LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    url(r"^logout/$", LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    url(r'^switch/(?P<tenant_id>[^/]+)/$', views.switch,
        name='switch_tenants'),
    url(r'^switch_services_region/(?P<region_name>[^/]+)/$',
        views.switch_region,
        name='switch_services_region'),
    url(r'^switch_keystone_provider/(?P<keystone_provider>[^/]+)/$',
        views.switch_keystone_provider,
        name='switch_keystone_provider')
]
```

Comment: Yeah, it was that. 
I missed it, thanks a lot Willem.
My next error is *django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: registration/login.html*, I will try to solve it.

Thks again.

Comment: @jbacelo: well you somewhere specified a template `registration/login.html`, but it does not exists, or at least is not located in the template directories.

Comment: I haven't specified anything, this is a fresh install from the Openstack Horizon service tutorial, I'm fixing the bugs as they appear.